# Why do we need Exogeneity of Treatment in a Diff in Diff

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

One of the assumptions of DiD I learnt is that the treatment must be random and unrelated to the outcome. I'm a little bit confused about why we need this assumption.

If I look at the typical picture demonstrating how DiD works, it doesn't seem like endogeneity of treatment has any effects on how the estimation technique works. Suppose I have two cities, A and B. A has a higher crime level than B. Authorities in A don't like crimes, so they pass a law to increase the presence of police. The intervention is not unrelated to outcome, but suppose that the parallel trend assumption holds. Why can't I use DiD?

Is the assumption of exogeneity of treatment needed because we use linear regression to estimate the treatment effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose I have two cities, A and B. A has a higher crime level than B. Authorities in A don't like crimes, so they pass a law to increase the presence of police. The intervention is not unrelated to outcome, but suppose that the parallel trend assumption holds. Why can't I use DiD?

You can run the DiD model. You just can't claim that DiD tells you what the causal effect of the law on crime is.

This is because you won't be able to tell if it was the dislike of crimes that lowered the crimes or intervention. Perhaps cities where authorities dislike crime will always find some way of reducing them (turning blind eyes to vigilantes, increasing funding without any law change etc, presumably those authorities were put there by elections so that means locals might be tougher on crime).

Although you can still run the model to just get numerical difference between treatment and control without attributing any causal effect of intervention on outcomes, although that will be unlikely of any interest to most scholars/policy makers.

Comment: but if in absence of the treatment, the growth rate in A would have been the same in B, then wouldn't it be far to say that it was the treatment and not the care about crime that was the cause of reduction?

Comment: @Rainroad you can't because $\beta$ you estimate is not the average treatment effect on the treated anymore. If treatment is exogenous it just gives you a difference in outcomes between the group that could be caused by all manner of other things than the treatment. For example, as mentioned in my answer maybe what reduced crime was not the law but local vigilantes.  Endogeneity literally of treatment literally means the law was caused by something else, you don't know if its actually the law having effect or just 3rd cause causes both law and effect

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the econometrics that prevent you from *measuring* the difference in the difference when the treatment is endogenous. The concern is about *interpreting* the difference in the difference.

Take a fully endogenous example. Many people go on a diet before they get married. They go on that diet *because* they want to look nice for their wedding. We could run a difference in difference regression of people's weight 6 months before their wedding and also on the morning of their weddings. As a control population, we could compare people of similar age, gender, but not getting married (on the same day and 6 months earlier). If we ran this regression, we would find that the difference-in-difference was negative, that the people getting married lose weight relative to the control population over the period.

But the marriage doesn't *cause* the weight loss. Rather, the wedding and the weight loss have a common cause. If we randomly forced unmarried people to get married today, they wouldn't be lighter than they were 6 months earlier.

Returning to the example of the crime, the concern is not being able to distinguish between the effect of the endogenous treatment and the other endogenous responses. The effect measured is the total effect. So the city A folks might be going out less, becoming more likely to be armed, doing daylight activities and similarly adjusting to crime, and what the DiD is attributing to the change in police is actually the change to all the endogenous changes.

Comment: Ok I see your point that we need treatment to be uncorrelated with other factors that may potentially explain the outcome variable, but why do we need it to be unrelated to the outcome at baseline as well? Returning to the example I gave, what is the problem with it?